# TYPO3: User account can't upload files

Tags: typo3

I have a TYPO 4.7 site.

I have created an account for redactor to change content of the page, and I've created a filemount so that he can upload files, but when I click on "Select files", nothing happens.

I fear I might have screwed somehting of the permissions, but I cant imagine which one is it that is bad configured

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that is an flash issue? The user can deactivate using flash upload in his settings. In that case he will get the old upload modul. So, if that works, but the flash uploader does not, it is an flash issue.